# Reset iPad app content and settings from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, core-data

When testing my app from Xcode, in the iOS simulator I can select "Reset content and settings" so that the app can start with a clean slate. I'm mostly interested in wiping out the stored core data.

How do I achieve the same thing when I run the app on an actual iPad from Xcode (through USB)?
I don't want to change the actual app for this to do it programmatically, because I don't plan to release a reset option within the app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough, if you delete the app from your iPad. All content, which was created by your application will be removed as well.

But if you change your mind and plan to do it programmatically, this might help you:

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];


NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:NULL];
NSEnumerator *e = [contents objectEnumerator];
NSString *filename;
while ((filename = [e nextObject])) { 
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
}
```

Comment: `removePersistentDomainForName:` deletes the user defaults, but not all application data. In particular not the Core Data files, which the question was about.

Comment: As he doesn't want to do it programmatically it doesn't matter. Just delete the app and done.